# How to launch android application from URL in android?

Tags: java, android, url

Can anybody please tell me how to open android application from URL in android.

I am using following method to open application in android but it doesn't works for me.

```
<data android:scheme="application"/>
```

I am passing source of URL "application://[RandomText]"

Is it correct way to open application?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data android:host="www.put-your-website.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). An application must register itself to listen to intents sent using sendBroadcast(). After this the user is presented with a pop up to launch that application. (Similar to send functionality where you can choose to send using different applications)