# Open app from specific web view link

Tags: android, facebook-like

Hello everyone i have a big problem.
I have my app ready but I'd like to implement one more thing.
I'd like that if a user is surfing Facebook or the net via any browsers and he clicks on a specific link that has a specify word like football android ask him if he wants to open via browser or using my app.
Is that possible , any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396451/how-to-launch-android-application-from-url-in-android

Comment: yes it was a duplicate thanks, i follow what's inside here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609573/intercepting-links-from-the-browser-to-open-my-android-app but didn't work, no errors,but if i am on Facebook and click the link nothing happened,i tried on twitter and android ask me whit which app i want to open the link but mine is not there